# Hide MediaElement.js player

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

How can I hide a mediaelement.js player?? Actually I am playing two player simultaneously but I want to hide one while playing. I have found [mediaelement.js - How to hide Audio controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708037/mediaelement-js-how-to-hide-audio-controls)  question on stackoverflow but it just hide controls not the player.

I am using following code for my player which I want to hide.

```
<audio id="overlayplayer1" src="" autoplay type="audio/mp3" controls preload> 
  <embed src="" hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>
</audio>   in my html file
```

and

```
this.MEplayer1 = new MediaElementPlayer('#overlayplayer1', {
            pluginPath: '../js/me281/',
            flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
            silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
            pauseOtherPlayers: false,
            enableAutosize: false,
            debug: false, 
            success: function (me, domobj) {
                console.log('player initiated successfully');
                ...
}
```

for my .js file.
Any help will be appreciated to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: You could try adding an event listener for the `playing` event, but I don't know how it'll work injunction with silverlight and fla files served for degradation. `$('#overlayplayer2').addEventListener('playing', function(){
        $('#overlayplayer1').hide();
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using

```
<div style="display:none">
```

Here is the code:

```
        <div style="display:none">
<audio id="overlayplayer1" src="" autoplay type="audio/mp3" controls preload hidden=true> 
</audio>
</div>
    </div>
```